# Can I have more semantic meaning in an http 404 error?

Tags: python, http, tornado, http-status-codes

I have a client-server interface realized using the module `requests` as client and `tornado` as server. I use this to query a database, where some dataitems may not be avaiable. For example the author in a query might not be there or the book-title.

Is there a recommended way to let my client know, what was missing? Like an `HTTP 404: Author missing` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTTP 404 responses can have a response body, I would put the detailed error message in the body itself. You can, for example, send the string `Author Not Found` in the response body. You could also send the response string in the format that your API already uses, e.g. XML, JSON, etc., so that every response from the server has the same basic shape.

Whether using code 404 with a `X Not Found` message depends on the structure of your API. If it is a RESTful API, where each URL corresponds to a resource, then 404 is a good choice if the resource itself is the thing missing. If a requested data field is missing, but the requested resource exists, I don't think 404 would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 is fixed in its meaning, see [Wikipedia's List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

You could choose a specific one of these status codes which fits better to your needs, and add some context on what's missing in the transmitted data (request's method "text", if I understood the documentation right).